# How to get data from xml api

Tags: javascript, php, xml, radio-button

I have an radio. This is xml api file...http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=E8FBFBE1-E50F-4E6A-BEA7-CA2E41F96D0B&apikey=cf41bd17-7638-4c10-b869-341555a65d7f&type=xml&previous=yes&next=yes&cover=yes&callmeback=yes&defaultcover=yes 
I want on my website show line artists and title... I have .php file (index.php). What code i must write for show artists and title on my website.

```
*Example:*
**IN XML:**

    <artists>Madonna<artist>
    <title> Hurry UP<title>

**ON MY WEBSITE I WANT:**
Artist: Madonna
Title: Hurry UP
```

EDIT:I dont understand...What i must write to .php file... Please write only what i must write to .php file

Comment: You're going to want to use [simpleXML()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), But you should also show your php and at least make some effort before coming and asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by parsing the XML using DOMDocument or SimpleXML.

Read the XML into your chosen library something like:

```
$url = http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=E8FBFBE1-E50F-4E6A-BEA7-CA2E41F96D0B&apikey=cf41bd17-7638-4c10-b869-341555a65d7f&type=xml&previous=yes&next=yes&cover=yes&callmeback=yes&defaultcover=yes 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Then to read out the artist:

```
$currentArtist = $xml->track->tracks->artists;
echo 'Current Artist :: ',$currentArtist;
```

Or whatever use you have for it